# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'. Did you mean: 'name'?

Tags: python, numpy

when i am doing this, i get this error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.array([1,2,3,4,3,2,1,4,5,2,4])

print(y)
plt.hist(y)
```

i get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\platform.py", line 831, in uname
    system, node, release, version, machine = infos = os.uname()
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'. Did you mean: 'name'?
```

How can I fix this is my python broken or something else because it works in jupyter notebook bur doesn't work in vs code. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: The error traceback doesn't point at your code at all. Do you get this error for other code as well? How do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

uname is originally a unix command and so is only available to unix like platform you can use platform instead

```
import platform
platform.platform()
#u can also use platform.platform()
```